# regex to find year/month substring

Tags: php, regex

Can someone help me with a regular expression to get the year and month from a text string?

Here is an example text string:

> `http://www.domain.com/files/images/2012/02/filename.jpg`

I'd like the regex to return `2012/02`.

Comment: What software are you using? What have you tried? What don't you understand?

Comment: don't know much about regex. Tried to read up on it but seemed very complicated to me. Was hoping someone here would help me out.

Comment: Alexis, I don't understand how regular expressions work. Looks like nonsense to me.
I'm using php if that matters.

Comment: @jens - **Well worth the effort of learning them.**  Super super useful tool.  They **are** however slightly complicated to grasp at first.  But like I said - it will pay off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex pattern would match what you need:

```
(?<=\/)\d{4}\/\d{2}(?=\/)
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape the slashes `(?<=\/)\d{4}\/d{2}(?=\/)`

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't get it to work earlier but escaping solved it.

Comment: Sorry, and I forgot the one for the decimal :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your situation and how much your strings vary - you might be able to dodge a bullet by simply using PHP's handy `explode()` function.

A simple demonstration - <sub>Dim the lights please...</sub>

```
$str = 'http://www.domain.com/files/images/2012/02/filename.jpg';
print_r( explode("/",$str) );
```

Returns :

```
Array
(
    [0] => http:
    [1] =>
    [2] => www.domain.com
    [3] => files
    [4] => images
    [5] => 2012      // Jack
    [6] => 02        // Pot!
    [7] => filename.jpg
)
```

The `explode()` function ([docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)), splits a string according to a "delimiter" that you provide it.  In this example I have use the `/` (slash) character.

So you see - you can just grab the values at 5th and 6th index to get the date values.

Comment: ahh, didn't think of that. I do like the regex solution better though.

Comment: Me too :)  Its pretty :) But this is an alternative - come back to this once you have [pulled all your hair out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/558021) over regular expressions ;) **JOKES**